# Chain rule for tensor of family of tensor fields

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

- Let $f_\tau$ be a $\mathbb R$-family (parameter $\tau$) of diffeomorphisms that map from $\mathbb R^4$ to $\mathbb R^4$. $f^*_\tau$ is the corresponding pullback (I think that is the correct term).
- Let $g$ be a two times covariant tensor field with components $g_{\mu\nu}$. I will call that $(2, 0)$-tensor field. This tensor serves as the metric tensor, but that is not important for this question.
- Let $R$ be the Ricci tensor, a $(2, 0)$-tensor that depends on the metric tensor $g$.

In the physics problem that I am working on right now, the term
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} R_{\mu\nu}(f^*_\tau g) \bigg|_{\tau = 0} $$
comes up. I am not really sure how chain rule works for those general tensors.

Let $\tilde g := f^*_\tau g$. Is the following correct?
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} R_{\mu\nu}(f^*_\tau g) =
\sum_{\alpha, \beta} \frac{\partial R_{\mu\nu}}{\partial \tilde g_{\alpha\beta}} \frac{\partial [f^*_\tau g]_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial \tau} $$